# Cordova File plugin does not supported FileWriter.write(blob)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

So how can I do file download in Cordova?

```
writeFile(fileEntry, blob, fileName) {
  // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry
  fileEntry.createWriter(fileWriter => {
    fileWriter.onwrite = this.onWriteEnd
    fileWriter.onerror = this.onWriteError
    fileWriter.write(blob) // does not working
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do, what error you are getting and what you have already tried to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.